# Kubuntu 12.04 - Touchpad and keyboard stopped working at random

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, kubuntu, touchpad

As in the title, I've got this problem with my Kubuntu 12.04.

At first I've thought that the whole system was hung, but it happened again 5 minutes ago and, while the keyboard and the touchpad stopped working, the music was still playing, so I guess that's just an "input" problem, because the system was still working!

Any solution?

Is there some data that you need to know about my setup?

EDIT:

Added my `lshw` outout

```
    description: Notebook
    product: N53SV ()
    vendor: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
    version: 1.0
    serial: B2N0AS17695408A
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=N uuid=8083F2DA-A43E-E081-3F3F-BCAEC55F8AA1
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: N53SV
       vendor: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: BSN12345678901234567
       slot: MIDDLE
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: N53SV.214
          date: 08/10/2011
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 2496KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: CPU 1
          size: 800MHz
          capacity: 4GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=1 threads=2
        *-cache
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back instruction
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 40
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 10GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
             product: 99U5428-040.A00LF
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 0
             serial: 103C28C3
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
             product: HMT325S6BFR8C-H9
             vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
             physical id: 1
             serial: 58383D1F
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
             product: HMT325S6BFR8C-H9
             vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
             physical id: 2
             serial: 58183D19
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
             product: HMT325S6BFR8C-H9
             vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
             physical id: 3
             serial: 58183C8F
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 09
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:db000000-dc0fffff ioport:c0000000(size=301989888)
           *-generic UNCLAIMED
                description: Unassigned class
                product: Illegal Vendor ID
                vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: ff
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 66MHz
                capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list
                configuration: latency=255 maxlatency=255 mingnt=255
                resources: memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:dc000000-dc07ffff
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:47 memory:dc400000-dc7fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:e000(size=64)
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei latency=0
             resources: irq:48 memory:df00b000-df00b00f
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:df008000-df0083ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:49 memory:df000000-df003fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41 ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:de600000-deffffff ioport:d4200000(size=10485760)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 ioport:b000(size=4096) memory:ddc00000-de5fffff ioport:d3700000(size=10485760)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
                vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 01
                serial: 48:5d:60:f2:2c:fd
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.2.0-24-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:17 memory:ddc00000-ddc0ffff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:43 ioport:a000(size=4096) memory:dd200000-ddbfffff ioport:d2c00000(size=10485760)
           *-usb
                description: USB controller
                product: FL1000G USB 3.0 Host Controller
                vendor: Fresco Logic
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 04
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:19 memory:dd200000-dd20ffff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:44 ioport:9000(size=4096) memory:dc800000-dd1fffff ioport:d2100000(size=10485760)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 06
                serial: bc:ae:c5:5f:8a:a1
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:46 ioport:9000(size=256) memory:d2104000-d2104fff memory:d2100000-d2103fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:df007000-df0073ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi0
             logical name: scsi2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:45 ioport:e0b0(size=8) ioport:e0a0(size=4) ioport:e090(size=8) ioport:e080(size=4) ioport:e060(size=32) memory:df006000-df0067ff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: ST9750420AS
                vendor: Seagate
                physical id: 0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 0002
                serial: 5WS0A7QR
                size: 698GiB (750GB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=e0c5913d
              *-volume:0
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: MSDOS5.0
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   version: FAT32
                   serial: 4ce5-3acb
                   size: 3004MiB
                   capacity: 3004MiB
                   capabilities: primary fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
              *-volume:1
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   logical name: /
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: c198cc2a-d86a-4460-a4d5-3fc0b21e439c
                   size: 28GiB
                   capacity: 28GiB
                   capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2012-03-15 16:53:54 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2012-05-02 18:52:04 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered mounted=2012-05-09 19:06:01 state=mounted
              *-volume:2
                   description: Windows NTFS volume
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                   logical name: /dev/sda3
                   version: 3.1
                   serial: 4c1cdebc-ec09-2947-a3b5-c1f9f1cddc1c
                   size: 152GiB
                   capacity: 152GiB
                   capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                   configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2011-02-22 16:02:47 filesystem=ntfs label=OS state=clean
              *-volume:3
                   description: Extended partition
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                   logical name: /dev/sda4
                   size: 514GiB
                   capacity: 514GiB
                   capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
                 *-logicalvolume:0
                      description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                      physical id: 5
                      logical name: /dev/sda5
                      capacity: 10GiB
                      capabilities: nofs
                 *-logicalvolume:1
                      description: HPFS/NTFS partition
                      physical id: 6
                      logical name: /dev/sda6
                      capacity: 504GiB
           *-cdrom
                description: DVD-RAM writer
                product: BD-MLT UJ240AS
                vendor: MATSHITA
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /dev/cdrw
                logical name: /dev/dvd
                logical name: /dev/dvdrw
                logical name: /dev/sr0
                version: 1.00
                capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
                configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:df005000-df0050ff ioport:e040(size=32)
```

Comment: I have the same problem! I am on lenovo ideapad y550 and random hung annoys me. None keyboard or mouse works!

Comment: It's not a definitve solution, but I have this script saved in a file on my desktop whenever this happens: `sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sleep 2; sudo modprobe psmouse` (provided they don't freeze at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

Make a file psmouse.conf with this text
options `psmouse proto=imps`
save as root in `/etc/modprobe.d/`
The mouse problem then will be OK

Comment: Does this work if I'm using a touchpad instead of a mouse? And what about my keyboard?

Comment: first try to check if your keyboard and mouse is listed in the list by issuing the command `sudo lshw`

Comment: I've added the output of `lshw` and seems that they're not listed here. While writing this comment, it happened again. I could move the mouse, but clicking or using the keyboard was uneffective !

Comment: Try adding the USB mouse and keyboard and check if it works. I think the problem is only with the internal keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on my ASUS EEEPC 1015B with 12.04x64, this is a kernel issue purely as the new 12.10 Quantal runs fine on the same machine.