# Laptop touchpad not working

Tags: selinux

i recently installed Ubuntu 13.4 on my old lenovo3000y500.first the all things was going right.when i reboot my laptop the problem arise after the reboot the laptop won't detect the Touchpad.i am not able to scroll and the left and right click button are also not working

so guys please help me to recover from this problem

Comment: It's not a definitve solution, but it works whenever this happens: sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sleep 2; sudo modprobe psmouse This trick works for me I saw it in this answer:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/134531/kubuntu-12-04-touchpad-and-keyboard-stopped-working-at-random#comment200799_134531