# Touchpad only works after hard reset. HP laptop Ubuntu 14.04.02

Tags: touchpad

I can only get my trackpad to work by shutting down, removing the battery and holding down the power button for 15 seconds. If I do a normal reboot the trackpad no longer works, buttons included.

xinput list gives this output

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Truevision HD                          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

But on restart the PS/2 Synaptics Touchpad dissapears.

Also in System Settings the mouse/touchpad settings has nothing about the touchpad at all.

I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.10 and 15.04 and the touchpad does not work in either running as a live session.

This seems to be a common problem but I have not been able to find any help other than the hard reset option which is very time consuming.

Thank you

***UPDATE*** As per suggested below installing the latest kernel fixed the touchpad but broke all internet connectivity. Upon installing extras connectivity returned but the touchpad is gone again. Any help?

Comment: Have tried to install one of the new kernel images ? For instance `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic`

Comment: Installing the new kernel fixed the mouse but i have lost all internet. I can't connect with wireless or a cable

Comment: You need to install also the extra packages. `sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-3.19.0-18-generic linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic`. I thought they would be automatically added to the installation.

Comment: Thanks Harris, ironically installing the extras enabled the internet again but disabled the touchpad so it is back to square one

Answer (score 0):

It's not a definitve solution, but it works whenever this happens:

`sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sleep 2; sudo modprobe psmouse`

This trick works for me I saw it in this answer: [Kubuntu 12.04 - Touchpad and keyboard stopped working at random](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134531/kubuntu-12-04-touchpad-and-keyboard-stopped-working-at-random#comment200799_134531)

Comment: Thank you, I tried the command you suggested and it did not change anything